# how to send attached mail form azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using Send email task to send the mails.

Usecase :

I am able to build the andriod application and able to generate apk file and published that apk by using Publish Artifact.

When i try to send the generated apk throught mail.it is showing the below error message.
**

> [error]Access to the path 'D:\a\1\drop' is denied

**[image]

But with out attachment I am able to send mails.Only i am getting problem with attached mails.
[image]

Comment: can anybody responsed with solutions

Answer (score 0):

From the second screenshot, I notice you are defining "Attachment (absolute path)" as `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

I could locate this target file by `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\*.zip`

[image]

Try `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\*.apk`

Comment: HI Kim Thanks for reponding

Comment: I tried with $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\*.apk this but i am getting [error]Unable to find the specified file

Comment: Attachment: D:\a\1\a\ *.apk

Comment: VM I am using is Microsoft self host VM

Comment: getting same [error]Access to the path 'D:\a\1\drop' is denied

Comment: Not sure whether your issue is related to the SMTP Server, do you have any latest update on this post? Thanks